# RxJava- Consolidating multiple, infinite Observable<List<T>>?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

Here is a fun little RxJava puzzle I am dealing with. Let's say I have an `Observable<List<Parent>> infiniteParentListStream` that is infinite, and each `Parent` has an `Observable<List<Child>> infiniteChildListStream` property which also is infinite.

I want to take all `Parent` instances in the emitted `List<Parent>`, and consolidate each of their emitted `List<Child>` items into a single, whole `List<Child>` reflecting all children of all parents.

The fact the `Observable<List<Child>> infiniteChildListStream` property in `Parent` is infinite is making the `toList()` task a little challenging.

```
public final class NestedInfiniteTest {

    private static final BehaviorSubject<Integer> parentSubject = BehaviorSubject.create(1);
    private static final BehaviorSubject<Integer> childSubject = BehaviorSubject.create(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Observable<List<Parent>> infiniteParentListStream = parentSubject
                .map(i -> Arrays.asList(new Parent(), new Parent(), new Parent()))
                .cache(1);

        Observable<List<Child>> allCurrentChildren = infiniteParentListStream.<List<Child>>flatMap(parentList ->
                Observable.from(parentList)
                        .flatMap(p -> p.getInfiniteChildListStream().flatMap(Observable::from)).toList()
        ).cache(1);

        allCurrentChildren.subscribe(cl -> System.out.println("WHOLE CHILD LIST SIZE: " + cl.size()));
    }

    private static final class Parent {
        private final Observable<List<Child>> infiniteChildListStream = childSubject
                .map(i -> Arrays.asList(new Child(), new Child(), new Child())).cache(1);

        public Observable<List<Child>> getInfiniteChildListStream() {
            return infiniteChildListStream;
        }
    }
    private static final class Child {

    }
}
```

One workaround solution I found, of course, is to turn the `infiniteChildListStream` finite by calling `first()`. But this is less than desirable since it no longer updates.

```
Observable<List<Child>> allCurrentChildren = infiniteParentListStream.<List<Child>>flatMap(parentList ->
        Observable.from(parentList)
                .flatMap(p -> p.getInfiniteChildListStream().first().flatMap(Observable::from)).toList()
).cache(1);
```

I feel like there is a way to manually call `Observable.create()` or use `flatMap()` tricks to resolve this. Is there a better way to do this and to keep things reactive with the infinite sources? In my real application outside this SSCCE, these observables are infinite because the data sources driving `Parent` and `Child` could change and emit new values...

I guess the root of my question is how do I take multiple infinite `Observable<List<T>>` and consolidate them to a single `Observable<List<T>>` ?

Comment: UPDATE: I think `Observable.combineLatest()` might provide a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out by using `Observable.combineLatest()`. To enhance testing, I also modified the source observables to create varying `List` sizes based on the subject's pushed integer value. This looks like it works beautifully.

```
public final class NestedInfiniteTest {

    private static final BehaviorSubject<Integer> parentSubject = BehaviorSubject.create(1);
    private static final BehaviorSubject<Integer> childSubject = BehaviorSubject.create(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Observable<List<Parent>> infiniteParentListStream = parentSubject
                .map(i -> IntStream.range(0,i).mapToObj(val -> new Parent()).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .cache(1);

        Observable<List<Child>> allCurrentChildren = infiniteParentListStream.flatMap(parentList ->
                Observable.<Observable<List<Child>>>create(s -> {
                    parentList.stream().map(Parent::getInfiniteChildListStream).forEach(s::onNext);
                    s.onCompleted();
                })
                .toList() //List<<Observable<List<Child>>>>
                .flatMap(consolidatedChildList -> Observable.combineLatest(consolidatedChildList, new FuncN<List<Child>>() {
                    @Override
                    public List<Child> call(Object... args) {
                        ArrayList<Child> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (Object obj : args) {
                            list.addAll((List<Child>) obj);
                        }
                        return list;
                    }
                }))
        );


        allCurrentChildren.subscribe(cl -> System.out.println("WHOLE CHILD LIST SIZE: " + cl.size()));
        childSubject.onNext(10);
        parentSubject.onNext(5);
        childSubject.onNext(2);
    }

    private static final class Parent {
        private final Observable<List<Child>> infiniteChildListStream = childSubject
                .map(i -> IntStream.range(0, i).mapToObj(val -> new Child()).collect(Collectors.toList())).cache(1);

        public Observable<List<Child>> getInfiniteChildListStream() {
            return infiniteChildListStream;
        }
    }
    private static final class Child {

    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
WHOLE CHILD LIST SIZE: 1   //parentSubject = 1, childSubject = 1
WHOLE CHILD LIST SIZE: 10  //parentSubject = 1, childSubject = 10
WHOLE CHILD LIST SIZE: 50  //parentSubject = 5, childSubject = 10
WHOLE CHILD LIST SIZE: 2   //parentSubject = 5, childSubject = 2, adjusting
WHOLE CHILD LIST SIZE: 42  //adjusting
WHOLE CHILD LIST SIZE: 34  //adjusting
WHOLE CHILD LIST SIZE: 26  //adjusting
WHOLE CHILD LIST SIZE: 18  //adjusting
WHOLE CHILD LIST SIZE: 10  //parentSubject = 5, childSubject = 2, done!
```

UPDATE: Created a Transformer to perform this task

```
public static class CombinedListTransformer<T,R> implements Observable.Transformer<List<T>,List<R>> {

    private final Func1<T,Observable<List<R>>> listMapper;

    public CombinedListTransformer(Func1<T,Observable<List<R>>> listMapper) {
        this.listMapper = listMapper;
    }
    @Override
    public Observable<List<R>> call(Observable<List<T>> sourceList) {
        return sourceList.flatMap(sl ->
            Observable.from(sl).map(t -> listMapper.call(t)).toList() //List<Observable<List<R>>
            .flatMap(consolidatedChildList -> Observable.combineLatest(consolidatedChildList, args -> {
                ArrayList<R> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Object obj : args) {
                    list.addAll((List<R>) obj);
                }
                return list;
            }))
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use sl -> Observable.from(sl).map(listMapper) instead of Observable.create?

Comment: Just updated, you are right it makes it a little less verbose.

Comment: listMapper is already a Func1 so you don't have to write t -> listMapper.call(t)

Comment: Oh yeah... I always forget that functions are objects too.